# node-http-proxy how to forward cookies to the proxy target

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to proxy an PHP api service, but I need to authenticated based on a session token.

Does node-http-proxy has options to forward the cookies to the target ?

Comment: `node-http-proxy` proxies the entire request, including all headers (so cookies as well).

Comment: Actually I didn't receive anything from headers from my PHP side, that's why I'm asking if that's the default.

Comment: Without more code it's hard to say.

Comment: What options are you passing with the request into node-http-proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is most likely you're accessing the service via http when the proxy is requesting https and the cookie is set to secure. So your browser won't send it when making a http call.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a problem like this once. In my case what happened was that though the original cookie was sent with the request, the response from the proxy did not have that cookie.

What I ended up doing was saving the cookie before making the proxy request and the adding it to the response coming back from the proxy. You can write to the response vookies doing something like this:

```
var setCookie = res._headers['set-cookie'].concat(testGroup);
res.setHeader('set-cookie', setCookie);
```